# convert keywords to their phonetic equivalents

Tags: php, mysql

We've been working with a good php Keyword Typo recognizer so far. But is there a way we can also convert certain characters to their phonetic ones?

Some examples are:

```
Konsole -> finds 'console' in the typo field in the mysql database
Vinny -> finds 'vinnie'
```

So what we are looking for is a script that changes these commom chararcters to their obvious errors (c to k, i to y, y to ie etc.)

Comment: So this is one of the (few) things that SOUNDEX is (quite) good at.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php

Answer (score 1):

A script to convert the 'obvious' errors is quite hard, since both 'Vinny' and 'Vinnie' are names, and thus correctly written...

Colour and Color are both correctly written and sound exactly the same...

What you can do, however, is create a database with 'correct' spelling and test them against that table using 'soundex':

```
SELECT * FROM correct_words WHERE "vinny" SOUNDS LIKE correct_col;
```

If 'Vinnie' is in that list, that will return it :-)

More on [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way to work with this, because there are not that many mistakes when thinking in phonetic terms.

```
$_POST[keywordlist] = "vinny konsole mkbrian";

$inputChars = array("y","k","mk","ia");
$changeChars = array("ie","c","mc","ai");

for($i=0;$i < strlen($_POST[keywordlist]);$i++){
    $keywords = str_replace($inputChars, $changeChars,$_POST[keywordlist]);
}
```

The output will give this prefred way to put it:

```
vinnie console mcbrain
```

Of course, the inputChars and changeChars must be switched when inserting it in a database typo column, otherwise you will still be looking for the correct spelling :-)

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: you do realize that 'wreck' suddenly is 'wrecc', 'why' suddenly is 'whie' etc ?